# SFML 2.5.1 and CodeBlocks with GCC 5.1.0 - project compiling errors

Tags: gcc, cmake, codeblocks, sfml

I have downloaded an SFML 2.5.1 package for the CodeBlocks (GCC 5.1.0 TDM (SJLJ)) and even after following the SFML guide I still can't launch my app in this IDE. I tried multiple ways but I failed. Can somebody give me some hints about the problem by concluding from error logs? Thanks. My compiler is GCC 5.1.0 and my code is an example from [the SFML site](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php). 
Built by:

1 Dynamic libraries from an SFML package. The project builds without errors, but when I lunch the program I get this message:

> Cannot find the entry point of procedure
>   _ZNKSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE12find_last_ofEPKcj
>   in DLL-file [project path] sfml-system-d-2.dll

(This error occurs for all libraries - system, graphics, and window).

2 Static libraries from an SFML package:

```
||=== Build: Release in SFML example (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SFML-2.5.1\lib\libsfml-graphics-s.a(Shader.cpp.obj):Shader.cpp|| undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned int&, unsigned int)'|
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SFML-2.5.1\lib\libsfml-graphics-s.a(Shader.cpp.obj):Shader.cpp|| undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned int&, unsigned int)'|
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SFML-2.5.1\lib\libsfml-graphics-s.a(Shader.cpp.obj):Shader.cpp|| undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned int&, unsigned int)'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

After this, I decided to build SFML with CMake and the CodeBlock makefile.

3 Built static libraries ("include" comes from an SFML package, as well as openal32 and freetype dll):

```
||=== Build: Release in SFML example (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc4)||undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf3)||undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xea)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x12a)||undefined reference to `sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned int)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13a)||undefined reference to `sf::Color::Green'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x149)||undefined reference to `sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x161)||undefined reference to `sf::Window::isOpen() const'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x198)||undefined reference to `sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1c9)||undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1e0)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f7)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1ff)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x20d)||undefined reference to `sf::Window::display()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x231)||undefined reference to `sf::Window::close()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x246)||undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x250)||undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x255)||undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x260)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2e3)||undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2ed)||undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2f2)||undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2fd)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 23 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

4 Built dynamic libraries ("include" comes from a package):

```
||=== Build: Release in SFML example (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc5)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf5)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xed)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x12e)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf11CircleShapeC1Efj'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x133)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5Color5GreenE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x14f)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5Shape12setFillColorERKNS_5ColorE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x172)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK2sf6Window6isOpenEv'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1a9)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window9pollEventERNS_5EventE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1db)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f3)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f8)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x214)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget4drawERKNS_8DrawableERKNS_12RenderStatesE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x223)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x242)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x24c)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x26a)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5ShapeD2Ev'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x276)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2ee)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x30c)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5ShapeD2Ev'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x318)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 21 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

5 The only time when I successfully launch an sfml code (but outside the codeblocks) was when I followed instructions [of this video](https://youtu.be/UM93glM0Fhs). So I tried to build the SFML libraries this way: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS = false and SMFL_USE_STATIC_STD_LIBS = true.

```
||=== Build: Release in SFML example (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc4)||undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf3)||undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xea)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x12a)||undefined reference to `sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned int)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13a)||undefined reference to `sf::Color::Green'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x149)||undefined reference to `sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x161)||undefined reference to `sf::Window::isOpen() const'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x198)||undefined reference to `sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1c9)||undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1e0)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f7)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1ff)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x20d)||undefined reference to `sf::Window::display()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x231)||undefined reference to `sf::Window::close()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x246)||undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x250)||undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x255)||undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x260)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2e3)||undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2ed)||undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2f2)||undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2fd)||undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 23 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original error most likely originates from a difference in C++ standard flag for the pre-compiled binaries (probably no `-std=c++11`) and your project settings.

For a successful linking against SFML, I recommend:

- Make sure you follow the official tutorial step by step without skipping anything.
- If you link statically:

  - Don't forget to define SFML_STATIC in the project settings
  - Don't forget to link all the dependencies
- Linking order matters, use the [rule of thumb](https://dev.my-gate.net/2018/01/10/rule-of-thumb-linking-order/) "X depends on Y, so X comes before Y"
- And always make sure to use the same compiler version to compile SFML and to build your application